# Android won't allow me to get a photo from the gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

Can anyone please explain to me why this code allows me to take a photo and show it in an image button but not when i try to get the picture from the gallery . It doesn't show any errors .

```
 final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel"};

    final AlertDialog.Builder constructor = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    constructor.setTitle("Añadir Foto!");
    constructor.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                PROFILE_PIC_COUNT = 1;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                PROFILE_PIC_COUNT = 1;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent,SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                PROFILE_PIC_COUNT = 0;
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    img_header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            constructor.show();
        }
    });
```

This is the onActivityResult method:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent_imagen) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent_imagen);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                setFoto(intent_imagen);
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                setFoto(intent_imagen);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void setFoto(Intent intent_imagen) {
    Bitmap foto;
    foto=getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap((Bitmap)intent_imagen.getExtras().get("data"), 190, 165, true));
    img_header.setForeground(null);
    img_header.setImageBitmap(foto);
}
```

Comment: You should request permission dynamically.

Comment: this one?<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Use like this `if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_SETTINGS);
        } else {
            writeSetting();
        }`

Comment: Becasuse it was dangerous permission.

Comment: You can use this Library [https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/permissions-dispatcher/PermissionsDispatcher) .It was more easier.

Comment: @Franker you can use this code to set run time permission.https://github.com/Goldenmace/droid-RuntimePermissions it was a simple coding to set runtime permission.